# Bad configuration option: AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEY

Tags: rhel, configuration, sshd

I am running `RHEL 6.7` with the following configuration for `sshd`

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.80 2008/07/02 02:24:18 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# Disable legacy (protocol version 1) support in the server for new
# installations. In future the default will change to require explicit
# activation of protocol 1
Protocol 2

AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=RSAONLY

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
AllowGroups sshusers
LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 3

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no
UsePAM yes

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding no
#X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
ClientAliveInterval 900
ClientAliveCountMax 0
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
Banner /etc/issue

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
# Added for DISA GEN005538
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# Added for DISA GEN005539
Compression delayed
# Added for DISA GEN005526
KerberosAuthentication no
# FIPS 140-2 Encryption (Highest Level using Counter Mode)
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
MACs hmac-sha1
```

When I start up `sshd` and the startup gets to line 23 `AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=RSAONLY` of the configuration file, I get the following error

```
Starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 23: Bad configuration option: AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

I have looked at the RHEL documentation and configuration options which say this is a valid option syntax for the `sshd` configuration file, why does mine keep failing if this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS` is valid not in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file but in `/etc/sysconfig/sshd`

Comment: Thanks, just reread the instructions and missed the sysconfig part.

Answer (score 0):

`AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=RSAONLY` is a service setting which belongs in `/etc/sysconfig/sshd`, not part of the sshd configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`